# Dynamic HTML table with rowspan in R?

Tags: html, r, html-table

For example, suppose I have a `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(gene = 'RHO', ref = 123456, totalHits = 13,
                 diseases = c('Multiple Myeloma\nMultiple Myeloma\nMultiple Myeloma\nMultiple Myeloma'),
                 relations = c(' depend\neffect\nexamine\nincrease'),
                 entrez = 1233)
```

I want to dynamically create an HTML table that appears like the following. However, after looking through the `DT` and `htmlTable` packages, I cannot find clear documentaion on how to handle this `rowspan` behavior. It appears `DT` [cannot handle this](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/346), and I can only find examples of `colspan`-like behavior for `htmlTable` package. Keep in mind, my intention is to create the table dynamically. This is going to be with in a Shiny app, so I might have more than a single row, like I have in this example, in which the "Gene" would be the same, but the "Reference" would be different. Or, more than 4 entries under the "Diseases" column, which should match up horizontally with those entries in the "Relations" column. Any suggestions?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    thead {
      color: black;
    }
    
    tbody {
      color: blue;
    }
    
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>geneSymbol</th>
      <th>reference</th>
      <th>totalHits</th>
      <th>diseases</th>
      <th>relations</th>
      <th>entrez</th>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=4>RHO</td>
      <td rowspan=4>123456</td>
      <td rowspan=4>16</td>
      <td>Multiple Myeloma</td>
      <td>depend</td>
      <td rowspan=4>1233</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Multiple Myeloma</td>
      <td>effect</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Multiple Myeloma</td>
      <td>examine</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Multiple Myeloma</td>
      <td>increase</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</html>
```